# how to loop over fyne.CanvasObject in fyne in golang

Tags: go, fyne

the question is. i have `NewVScroll` in the `NewVScroll` i have `NewVBoxLayout` in `NewVBoxLayout` i have `NewButton` . **the problem is when i press the `NewButton` it should loop over `NewVScroll` and then loop over `NewVBoxLayout` to find `NewButton`** . but i don't know how to do it in fyne because i can't loop over **`var v1 fyne.CanvasObject`**

the error is : **`cannot range over v1 (variable of type fyne.CanvasObject)`**

this is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

var cEntries *fyne.Container

func FindObject(object fyne.CanvasObject, objects []fyne.CanvasObject) (int, bool) {
    for k1, v1 := range objects {
        for _, v2 := range v1 {// the problem is here. i can't loop over fyne.CanvasObject
            if v2 == object {
                return k1, true
            }
        }
    }
    return 0, false
}

func w1() *fyne.Container {
    wb := widget.NewButton("", nil)

    wb.OnTapped = func() {
        index, isin := FindObject(wb, cEntries.Objects)
        fmt.Println(index, isin)
    }

    return container.New(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), wb)
}

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("")

    wbAdd := widget.NewButton("+", nil)
    cEntries = container.New(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), wbAdd, w1())

    wbAdd.OnTapped = func() {
        cEntries.Add(w1())
    }

    wsEntries := container.NewVScroll(cEntries)

    w.SetContent(wsEntries)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is a container, so in general you could iterate `v1.(*fyne.Container).Objects`.

However it looks like you could avoid looping in your code because the button always refers to an index that is set when the button is added - so you could pass the current `index` (length) to `w1` and then increment it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop over **`NewVBoxLayout`** because it is **`fyne.CanvasObject`** then if you want to know the index of the layout that contain this widget **`NewButton`** you can do it by just search for **`NewVBoxLayout`** in **`NewVScroll`**
this is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

var cEntries *fyne.Container

func FindObject(object fyne.CanvasObject, objects []fyne.CanvasObject) (int, bool) {
    for k1, v1 := range objects {
        if v1 == object {
            return k1, true
        }
    }
    return 0, false
}

func w1() *fyne.Container {
    wb := widget.NewButton("", nil)
    c := container.New(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), wb)
    wb.OnTapped = func() {
        index, isin := FindObject(c, cEntries.Objects)
        fmt.Println(index, isin)
    }

    return c
}

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("")

    wbAdd := widget.NewButton("+", nil)
    cEntries = container.New(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), wbAdd, w1())

    wbAdd.OnTapped = func() {
        cEntries.Add(w1())
    }

    wsEntries := container.NewVScroll(cEntries)

    w.SetContent(wsEntries)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

see in this code you make the container that handle the button and then you search for the container that contain this button